# Why am I getting invalid filter for this custom filter?

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I'm trying to make the template print something based on a condition. It is getting the scores from a database and, based on the score, it states the medal:

```
{% for person in comp.round_1_set.all|order_by:"-score" %}

        <tr>
        <td> {{person.score|gol_sil}}
        </td>

        </tr>

    {%endfor%}
```

I tried doing a `{% if person.score > 10 %}` type of thing but I got an error for that. I guess it can't be done in the template. I then created a filter with this code:

```
   @register.filter_function
   def gol_sil(score):
    if score < 20:
        medal = " Silver "
    else:
        medal = " "
    return medal
```

and applied it with

```
 {{person.score|gol_sil}}
```

However I get an invalid filter error, why is this?

I cant do it in views because I'm using a `.set_all` to get the individuals in the template, any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you're getting when you use `{% if person.score > 10 %}` ?

Comment: Rather, you should show the error you get with the filter. Firstly, there is no `register.filter_function`. Secondly, are you sure you have loaded the tags in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this url for creating a filter

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/
2. http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html/

as i guess you have some error in the line containing @register.filter_function